# XSLT - Key function to get single value

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have the following xml

```
<Results>
    <form-type>orderform-B</form-type>
    <data>
      <form-data>
        <field>
           <name>productid-1</name>
           <value>Yes</value>
        </field>
        <field>
           <name>productid-1-qty</name>
           <value>2</value>
         </field>
         <field>
            <name>productid-3</name>
            <value>Yes</value>
         </field>
         <field>
            <name>productid-4</name>
            <value>Yes</value>
         </field>
         <field>
            <name>productid-4-qty</name>
            <value>2</value>
         </field>
         <field>
            <name>product-type</name>
            <value>productid-5-xl</value>
         </field>
         <field>
            <name>someother-field</name>
            <value>xyz</value>
         </field>
      </form-data>
    </data>
  </Results>
```

And the following XSLT to calculate order total:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="pricelist">
    <item id="productid-1">5</item> 
    <item id="productid-2">5</item> 
    <item id="productid-3">5</item> 
    <item id="productid-4">5</item>
    <item id="productid-5-sm">5</item>
    <item id="productid-5-md">10</item>
    <item id="productid-5-xl">15</item> 
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:key name="price" match="item" use="@id" />
<xsl:key name="qty" match="field" use="name" />

<xsl:template match="/Results">
    <total>
        <xsl:variable name="charges">
                 <xsl:apply-templates select="data/form-data/field[starts-with(name, 'productid-') or starts-with(value, 'productid-')]"/>

        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum($charges/charge)" />
    </total>    
</xsl:template>
   
<xsl:template match="field">
      <xsl:variable name="price" select="key('price', (name, value), $pricelist)" />
      <xsl:variable name="qty" select="key('qty', name)" />
      <xsl:if test="$price">
         <charge>
            <xsl:value-of select="$price * (if($qty) then $qty/value else 1)"/>
         </charge>
      </xsl:if> 
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want to get the value of qty using a key but what I have above returns both the qty fieldname and the qty value where as I only want to return the value so that I can do the calculation?

- How do I get just the qty value of the fields which have name ending with '-qty'?
- I have some products e.g. productid-3 on the order form where there is no quantity value field defined i.e. only the product ordered is listed in which case the quantity of the ordered product is assumed to be 1. How can I refactor the xslt to accommodate that as well so that the price * qty for the charge is price * 1?

*** UPDATE ***

Also on the order form, the product ordered can be listed in the value element due to variations of product type e.g.

```
<field>
    <name>product-type</name>
    <value>productid-5-xl</value>
</field>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the keys as defined, you can of course use `$qty/value` (instead of `$qty`) to select solely the value.

Or you would need to declare the key on `match="field[...]/value" use="../name"` to have the `key` function call return the `value` element.

Comment: doesn't seem to work, get error `Error executing XSLT at line 25 : Cannot convert string "" to double`

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="pricelist">
    <item id="productid-1">5</item> 
    <item id="productid-2">5</item> 
    <item id="productid-3">5</item> 
    <item id="productid-4">5</item> 
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:key name="price" match="item" use="@id" />
<xsl:key name="qty" match="field" use="name" />

<xsl:template match="/Results">
    <xsl:variable name="charges">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="data/form-data/field[value='Yes']"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <total>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum($charges/charge)" />
    </total>    
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="field">
    <xsl:variable name="price" select="key('price', name, $pricelist)" />
    <xsl:variable name="qty" select="key('qty', concat(name, '-qty'))" />
    <xsl:if test="$price">
        <charge>
            <xsl:value-of select="$price * (if($qty) then $qty/value else 1)"/>
        </charge>
   </xsl:if>    
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

P.S. Be careful with indiscriminate applying of templates; you don't want the built-in templates to kick in and litter your result with unwanted text nodes.

Comment: thanks that seems to work. What is the reason to restrict the match using the value 'Yes' e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="data/form-data/field[value='Yes']"/>`. Is that for performance? It's come to light some products will be listed where the type of product is defined in the value element in which case I've had to remove the above match - see my edited post. To find the price now I've updated the key to check both name and value elements `key('price', (name, value), $pricelist)`.

Comment: @michale.hor257k What I know is all products are prefixed with 'productid-' whether they appear in the name or value element. If restricting the match has any performance value how do I change `<xsl:apply-templates select="data/form-data/field[value='Yes']"/>` to check only field name or value elements which are prefixed with 'productid-'?

Comment: You have 2 `field` elements for each product ordered. One has the correct product ID, the other has the suffix "-qty" added to it. I tried to select the first one only by specifying the `[value='Yes']` predicate. If that does not fit the actual input structure, then another criteria needs to be found. Or possibly use the other one exclusively and either add the "-qty" suffix to the entries in pricelist or remove it when calling the key. Of course, if there is not something that is common to all ordered products, then no solution is possible.

Comment: not sure I follow. I've tried the updated code and it works without the predicate? To replicate try my updated code - just remove the predicate. I was just wondering if the predicate was there for performance or other benefit or if its there to just filter the product fields?

Comment: It is there to filter the fields to be processed. Naturally, reducing the fields being processed also improves performance. You may not see a difference in the result because the other fields do not generate a charge, so the sum is unaffected. But with so many variants of the input I would not take the chance.